# Write a program to swap odd and even bits in integer what is the minimum number of steps required?

Tags: c

I am trying to solve this one..and my code is as follows

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    int a, b = 0xaaaaaaaa, c = 0x55555555;
    printf("\n enter the number: \n");
    scanf("%d", & a);
    a = ((a & b) >> 1) | ((a & c) << 1);
    printf("\n %d", a);
}
```

..but i am getting some weird outputs..can anyone tell me what errors i m making?

Comment: whatever number i am entering i am getting one

Comment: @learning_bee: That's not the behaviour I get when I run your code.  (See e.g. http://ideone.com/BbJRh.)

Comment: @learning_bee: If you are going to change the + change it to | not ||.  But + works in this special case due to the data patterns.

Comment: @grok12: Could you elaborate one why that works and what the 'special cases' are?

Comment: @grok12-i changed that and saw that output is same 1

Comment: @tkeE2036: Since b has zeros in all the even numbered bits a&b will also have zeros in the even numbered bits.  Shifting right 1 position means all the odd numbered bits have zeros.  Similarly (a&c)<<1 has zeros in all the even numbered bits.  So adding them together gives the same result as oring them together because there are no carries generated by the add.

Comment: @learning_bee: It works for me.  I changed your %d's to %x's so I could work in hex making it easier to see the results.  Also I used unsigned int as valdo says.  I don't know why you get 1 as the result every time.  It is a mystery.

Answer (score 11):

Your idea is ok.
Perhaps you're getting the *weird outputs* because the bitshift don't work exactly as you may expect.

Your variables are of type `int`. Means - they are **signed**. Now, when you do the bitshift to a signed integer, there are additional rules about how the MSB bit is propagated. In simple words, when a signed integer is shifted right, the MSB isn't necessarily zero, it's copied from the old MSB value.

Try to replace `int` by `unsigned int`.

Comment: #include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
unsigned int a;
int b=0xaaaaaaaa,c=0x55555555;
printf("\n enter the number: \n");
scanf("%d",&a);
a=((a&b)>>1)||((a&c)<<1);
printf("\n %d",a);

}

Comment: are << and >> arithmetic shift by standard? I think logical shift is more useful

Comment: For signed integers, `<<` has **undefined behavior** on negative values or if a positive value overflows, and `>>` has implementation-defined behavior on negative values. Do not use bitshifts with signed types. Do as valdo said and change your type to `unsigned` and your code will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

on my pc this code worked perfectly
just changed the plus to |

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a, b = 0xaaaaaaaa, c = 0x55555555;
    printf("\n enter the number: \n");
    scanf("%d", & a);
    a = ((a & b) >> 1) | ((a & c) << 1);
    printf("\n %d\n", a);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
 enter the number: 
2
 1    
 enter the number: 
1
 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Though this solution takes more iterations, for understandable purposes try this

```
void swapEvenOddBits()    //function to swap the even and odd bits
{       
    unsigned int num=0,even=0,odd=0;
    scanf("%u",&num);  //enter the number

    for(int i=1; i<32; i=i+2){
        even=num&(1<<(i-1));   
        odd=num&(1<<i);     
        num=num-even-odd;   

        even=even<<1;       
        odd=odd>>1;         
        num=num+even+odd;   
        //printf("%u  %d:%d  %d:%d  \n",num,i-1,even,i,odd); //track iterations with this
    }
    printf("%u",num);  //end result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned char
swapOddEvenBits(unsigned char num)
{
    unsigned char odd_bits = num & 0xAA;
    unsigned char even_bits = num & 0x55;

    odd_bits >>= 1;
    even_bits <<= 1;

    return (odd_bits | even_bits);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason of your issue, is right shifting of signed integral number, where last two digits will have 11 as you ORed the last nibble with 1010. after OR the last nibble would look like 1101.

Answer (score -4):

```
import java.io.*;
public class EvenOdd {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int b = 0xaaaaaaaa, c = 0x55555555;
        System.out.println("enter number:");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String n="";
        try {
            n = br.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int num = Integer.parseInt(n);
        num = ((num&b)>>1)|((num&c)<<1);
        System.out.println(num);
    }
}
```