# How to swap neighbouring bits in ARM assembly

Tags: assembly, arm

How do I swap neighbouring bits in ARM v7? Example:

```
0x87654321 -> 0x4B9A8312

10000111011001010100001100100001 ->
01001011100110101000001100010010
```

Comment: The obvious portable way would be evenbits=0x5555...; `((x>>1) & evenbits) | ((x&evenbits) << 1)` to isolate the hi/lo bits of each pair and blend.  [Write a program to swap odd and even bits in integer what is the minimum number of steps required?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6495854).  Should be possible to optimize that with the barrel shifter, or just let a C compiler do that for you.

Comment: Are you optimizing for ARM mode or Thumb mode?  Thumb can do bit-pattern immediates so it's actually very good for constants like `0x55555555`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shift right by one, zero out the odd bits. <strike>Shift left, zero out the even bits.</strike> Zero out the odd bits, shift left. Finally, OR together.

EDIT: to zero out the odd bits, you use the AND command with the mask (i. e. a constant value) where all the odd bits have zeros. For a 32 bit ARM register, that's `0x55555555`. Bits 0 and 2 are one (bit values 1 and 4, together 5), bits 1 and 3 and zero, and so forth for every nybble.

Anyway, here goes the code. Assuming the source value is in `r0` and the result goes there too. Using Peter's idea where we zero the odd bits then shift rather than shift then zero out. Taking advantage of the ARM specific feature where the second operand can be shifted (or rotated) for free as a part of a larger  operation.

```
ldr r12, =0x55555555    //Load the mask for only even bits 

and r1, r12, r0, lsr #1 //r1 = (r0 >> 1) & mask, odd bits shifted right
and r2, r0, r12         //r2 = r0 & mask, even bits only
orr r0, r1, r2, lsl #1  //r0 = r1 | (r2 << 1), (odd bits shifted right) OR (even bits shifted left)
```

---

**Thumb2** can even use `0x55555555` as an immediate (because of the repeating bit pattern), but we'd still need 4 instructions because `and`-immediate can't shift the other register.  It is possible to make one of the instructions only 2 bytes long, though:

```
swap_thumb:
and   r1, r0, #0xaaaaaaaa     // odd bits: 4 bytes
and   r0, r0, #0x55555555     // even bits: 4 bytes
lsrs  r1, r1, #1              // 2 byte
orr   r0, r1, r0, lsl #1      // 4 bytes
```

This may have worse latency for superscalar CPUs in Thumb mode.  The same saving is possible with the original idea by using a low register (r0..7).  `ands r0, r3` is a 2-byte instruction, unlike `and`.

```
// Thumb 2 optimized version of the first version, overwrites r0 earlier
mov   r3, #0x55555555
and   r1, r3, r0, lsr #1         //r1 = (r0 >> 1) & mask, odd bits shifted right
ands  r0, r3                     //r0 &= mask, even bits only.  2 bytes
orr   r0, r1, r0, lsl #1         //r0 = r1 | (r0 << 1), (odd bits shifted right) OR (even bits shifted left)
```

Comment: I am new to ARM programming. How do I zero out odd/even bits? Could you show me what I'm looking for in ARM code?

Comment: You only need one mask constant; use it before shifting with one, after shifting with the other.  There's already a C duplicate ([Write a program to swap odd and even bits in integer what is the minimum number of steps required?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6495854)), if you're not going to optimize it for ARM specifically and make smaller and/or faster asm than compilers do (https://godbolt.org/z/kK4vRM), IMO there's no reason to answer this question, just maybe comment.

Comment: Got it! Thank you!